# Copy EventHandler of a Control to another

Tags: c#, controls

I have a Button (button1) , How can I copy it's Click property (I mean button1.Click) to another Button (button2), Something like:

```
button2.Click=button1.Click;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this.  Events only allow you to add or remove handlers, you cannot get a list of all of the handlers that they have.  It is a function that is *intentionally* removed from you.

You could keep track of the handlers you assign to a particular button yourself, independently, and then add those handlers to another button, to accomplish this effect.